# Spark : my Dataset is not updated after applying foreach

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset like this : `Dataset<MyModel> ds`, and `MyModel` has a field `name` (and many more fields).

I try to do this :

```
ds.foreach(r -> {
  r.setName("name");
});
return ds;
```

but I found that in the returned `ds`, the `name` field is not updated.

I want to know what should I do to to let `ds` gets updated ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a dataset, only make a new one

So you need to apply a map to the dataset, changing the fields, resulting in a new dataset

If MyModel was a case class you would do:

ds.map(x => x.copy(myField = "new value"))

As its a class instance I would recommend that in the map you make a copy of the object, modify the field(s) and return the copy.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Do you know how to achieve the same using map ?

Comment: MyModel is a simple POJO class, and it has indeed an encoder inside